# JavaScriptSerializer Serialize method returns input parameters - how to prevent?

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, serialization, asmx

I have an ASP.NET web service that returns JSON data (ASMX) - it uses the JavaScriptSerializer's Serialize method to serialize an object and return it back to the calling page via jQuery.
The problem is that it, not only returns the requested JSON data, but also returns the input parameters in the JSON string. Is there any way to prevent this from happening or can someone recommend a better serializer that does not return the input parameters back to the calling page?

```
<WebMethod> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function GetHGResults(startRowIndex As Integer, maximumRows As Integer, sortExpression As String, filterExpression As String, vendor_idx As Integer, manufacturer_idx As Integer, caliber_gauge_bore_idx As Integer, grains_weight As Integer, stock_status As String, search_phrase As String) As String
    HGSearch_Data.DBConnStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DefaultConnection").ToString

    Dim retval As List(Of HGSearchResult) = HGSearch_Data.GetLive_ItemsByPageSortOBJ(startRowIndex, maximumRows, sortExpression, filterExpression, vendor_idx, manufacturer_idx, caliber_gauge_bore_idx, grains_weight, stock_status, search_phrase)
    Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Return js.Serialize(retval)
End Function
```

an example output line:

> {"idx":4268,"lid":"163F7CA5-0B48-4DCD-8ADE-1EEDA4DC03DC","Vendor":"Go
>   Ammo","Manufacturer":"Wolf Performance","caliber_gauge_bore":"9mm
>   Makarov","grains_weight":"95","product_name":"Wolf 9MM X 18MM Makarov
>   Military Classic 95 Grain Bi Metal Full Metal Jacket, 1000 Round Case,
>   MC918FMJ","stock_status":"I","Updated":"224d21h13m","Price":200.5000,"units":"Case","total_rounds":1000,"price_per_round":0.2005,"startRowIndex":0,"maximumRows":0,"sortExpression":null,"filterExpression":null,"vendor_idx":0,"ammosection_idx":0,"manufacturer_idx":0,"brand_idx":0,"caliber_gauge_bore_idx":0,"search_phrase":null}

Note the input parameters at the end of the string. Makes no sense as to why MS would have this as a default behavior.

Comment: are you sure `GetLive_ItemsByPageSortOBJ` does not have these returned?

Comment: OMG! Suffering from code-fatigue. I was inheriting another class that had the params in it.  I should have noticed that the params were all set to default values (from the constructor). DOH! 


Thanks!